# Неправильная сортировка

Tags: c++

Задание следующее: Организуйте массив, содержащий 2n целых чисел. Отсортируйте элементы с нечётными индексами по возрастанию
Однако, сортировка, написанная мною не работает. Как можно исправить?

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int size;
    cout << "Введите кол-во элементов: ";
    cin >> size;
    size = 2 * size;
    cout << "Введите " << size << " элементов: ";
    int *mass;
    mass = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> mass[i];
    }
    cout << "Массив до сортировки: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << mass[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
    {
        bool flag = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < size - (i + 1); j+=2)
        {
            if (mass[j] > mass[j + 2])
            {
                flag = false;
                swap(mass[j], mass[j + 2]);
            }
        }
        if (flag) break;
    }
    cout << "\nМассива после сортировки: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << mass[i] << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Минимальным значением `i` является `0`. Это значит, что значение `j` во втором цикле может достигать `size - (0 + 1) - 1`, т.е. `size - 2`. Тогда внутри цикла доступ к элементу `mass[j + 2]` - это доступ к элементу `mass[size]`. А это вылет за пределы массива.

Следите за индексами и не вылетайте за пределы массивов.